# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo Java.lang.nullExeption

Tags: java, android

I'm new in android and I have a program that gives data from localhost via HTTP and parse it to XML and show it in a list in android.But I can't switch to new page(the page that shows the list).My program has  `java.lang.NullPointerException` exception and I can't found where It gives null.please help me and tell me what should I do.
this is error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sara.patientapplication/com.example.sara.patientapplication.ViewAllPatientActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.sara.patientapplication.ViewAllPatientActivity.onCreate(ViewAllPatientActivity.java:45)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)at 

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is my main layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".mainActivity">
<Button
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Show All Patients"
  android:id="@+id/ShowAllPatients"
  android:layout_marginTop="25dp"/>
  <Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add New Patient"
    android:id="@+id/AddNewP"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ShowAllPatients"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

and this is main Activity.there are a button and when I press it I expect go to a list but at that time exception Occurs.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    Button ShowAllPatient=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ShowAllPatients);
    Button AddNewPatient=(Button)findViewById(R.id.AddNewP);


    ShowAllPatient.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ViewAllPatientActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

this my list layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@android:id/list"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my the list activity:

```
public class ViewAllPatientActivity extends ListActivity {
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
XMLParser parser=new XMLParser();
static final String URL="http://localhost/AllPatient.php";
static final String Patient_ID="PatientId";
static final String First_Name="PatientFirstName";
static final String Last_Name="PatientLastName";
//static final String Blood_Type="BloodType";
//static final String Phone_Number="phoneNumber";
//static final String Practitioner_ID="practitionerId";
//static final String Email="Email";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_patient);



  //  String xml=parser.GetXml(URL);
    Document doc=parser.DomElement("http://localhost/AllPatient.php");

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(Patient_ID);
    for (int i=0;i<nl.getLength();i++){
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        map.put(Patient_ID,parser.GetValue(e , Patient_ID));
        map.put(First_Name,parser.GetValue(e,First_Name));
        map.put(Last_Name,parser.GetValue(e,Last_Name));
      //  map.put(Blood_Type,parser.GetValue(e,Blood_Type));
       // map.put(Phone_Number,parser.GetValue(e,Phone_Number));
       // map.put(Email,parser.GetValue(e,Email));
      //  map.put(Practitioner_ID,parser.GetValue(e,Practitioner_ID));

        menuItems.add(map);
    }
    ListAdapter adapter=new SimpleAdapter(this,menuItems,R.layout.list_item,
            new String[]{Patient_ID,First_Name,Last_Name},new int[]{R.id.pid,R.id.fName,R.id.lName});
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    ListView lv=getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String Patient_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText().toString();
            String First_name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fName)).getText().toString();
            String Last_name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lName)).getText().toString();

            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListPatient.class);
            in.putExtra(Patient_ID, Patient_id);
            in.putExtra(First_Name, First_name);
            in.putExtra(Last_Name, Last_name);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
}
```

and also I have some layout for a single list Item:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"><TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pid"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dip"
android:textSize="16dip"
android:textStyle="bold" />
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" /><TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" /></LinearLayout>
```

and

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/firstN"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/lastN"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/firstN"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Patient ID: "
    android:id="@+id/paId"
    android:layout_below="@+id/firstN"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/patientid"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/paId"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Blood Type: "
    android:id="@+id/bt"
    android:layout_below="@+id/paId"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/btype"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bt"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Phone Number: "
    android:id="@+id/pn"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bt"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/pnum"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pn"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Email: "
    android:id="@+id/em"
    android:layout_below="@+id/pn"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/mail"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/em"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

please help me.
thanks.

Comment: What's line 45 of ViewAllPatientActivity.java?

Comment: what is onCreate(ViewAllPatientActivity.java:45) in this line....................

Comment: I think doc is null have you check it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
  Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ViewAllPatientActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
```

To:

```
  Intent i=new Intent( mainActivity.this,ViewAllPatientActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
```

And check if:

```
 Document doc is null
```